# Loop through TableRow.Cells

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Say I have a table like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>TableCell Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <h1>TableCell Example</h1>
    <asp:table id="Table1" runat="server" 
        CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="3"
        Gridlines="both">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell Text="(0,0)" />
            <asp:TableCell Text="(0,1)" />
            <asp:TableCell Text="(0,2)" />
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell Text="(1,0)" />
            <asp:TableCell Text="(1,1)" />
            <asp:TableCell Text="(1,2)" />
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:table>

    </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I get the value of a cell in code.  Something like this:

```
For Each row As TableRow In objTable.Rows
  'How do I get the value of a cell here by ID?
Next
```

Can you get a cell value by index?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`TableRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow(v=vs.110).aspx) property called [`Cells`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablerow.cells(v=vs.110).aspx).
From MSDN:

> Gets a collection of TableCell objects that represent the cells of a row in a Table control.

The collection that this property returns is an instance of a class called [`TableCellCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecellcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) that has some need methods and properties such as [`Item`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecellcollection.item(v=vs.110).aspx) that gets you the table cell object by it's index.

also, you can use a `foreach` loop to get every [`TableCell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell(v=vs.110).aspx) in the collection, just like you did with the rows.

To get the `TableCell`'s text all you have to do is use it's property called... wait for it... [`Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell.text(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to get a cell value.  Can you get a cell value by index?